# Mozart/Oz: how to make record with Record.make

Tags: record, oz, mozart

I am trying to create a record from list using Record.make:

```
declare 
L=[z [a b] [1 2]]
{Record.make L.1 L.2 0}
```

but getting an error:

```
Expected type: feature
At argument: 1
```

How to make a second argument L.2 to be A 'feature' type? I assume L.2 is a [a b] list.

Answer (score 0):

`Record.make` creates a record with fresh (i.e. unbound) values. For example:

```
R = {Record.make label [a b]}
```

Maybe you want `List.toRecord` instead:

```
R = {List.toRecord label [a#1 b#2]}
```

Comment: Thanks. List.toRecord is also useful one!